# Add a css file to Kohana template

Tags: php, css, kohana

I want to add a css file to my template. I created the `template.php` into the folder : `kohana-v3.3.5\application\views`. Into this folder, I created an other folder called "css" and inside it, there is my `styles.css` with some code.

For now, my template file is :

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="/css/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 banner">
        Persyst
    </div>
</div>
<?php echo $content; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't understand why the links for my css files aren't working.

I saw something with `HTML:style()` but it doesn't work either.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `HTML::style()` is a good idea. The reason why it fails is because you put the assets folder inside the template folder. The latter is outside of web access (or should be) and is only used internally.

Kohana routes everything through the index.php file, so this is the level your stylesheets, scripts and images belong.

```
<html>
<head>
    <?php
    print HTML::style('vendor/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.css') ."\n"
        . HTML::style('assets/css/styles.css');
    ?>
```

With a directory structure like

- application
- modules
- system
- assets

  - css
  - js
- vendor

  - bootstrap